# Solr: create a multiValued field with a default that has multiple values?

Tags: java, solr

In my Solr schema, I want to create a multiValued field and set multiple values per default. Possible values are e.g. `A`, `B` and `C`. Can I just set some of them as a comma-separated list?

What I'd like to do is:

```
<field ...
       multiValued="true" 
       default="A,B"/>
```

Is this the right way? Unfortunately I couldn't find any hints in the official documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried many different ways by playing with schema but it seems like you cant put multiple default values by using schema only. The syntax that you wrote makes your multivalued field have a single entry like

```
<str>A,B</str>
```

which is not useful..

As there is no documentation about it i would recommend you to check [here - which you have probably checked before](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR)

You can try to hack solr source code to handle multiple default values on schema.. it could be also painful too, as the documentation is not that well even for the code itself, but i think it is possible to do..

p.s because i cant comment under your question i had to write this as answer